# Is it possible to use integers as names for arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, naming

I'm porting a game from the Sega Genesis to the Sega Saturn, and limited to C. I'm also following how the game is coded in Motorola 68000 assembly code as closely as possible, which requires many, many arrays of identical structures. I'm talking upwards of 300 or more. For the sake of organization and readability, it would be easier to name them with numbers instead of a string of characters

For example, I would *prefer*:

```
int 000[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int 001[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

As opposed to:

```
int zerozerozero[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int zerozeroone[4]  = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

But my compiler won't compile unless the array name starts with a character. Is there a way to do this? I suppose I could just throw an `a` at the front of the arrays, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays just do that.

Comment: what is the reason for not using an array of structures/arrays?

Comment: First, please consult the language's syntax. Second - what are you trying to accomplish? Why numbers for names?

Comment: @Walter Tross
It's because I'm developing for the Sega Saturn. I'm porting a game from the Sega Genesis to the Sega Saturn, and I'm following how the game works in 68k asm down to the tee.

Comment: Even if it would be possible, it is important to consider that such code essentially violates _DRY_ principle.

Comment: @Arkadiy
I am developing a collision system for the Sega Saturn. I'm using numbers for names because each number corresponds to something called a height mask, and giving each one a descriptive name would be nigh impossible, and ridiculously hard to manage. Using numbers means I can correlate the array name to what type of height mask it is.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski
I fail to see how it would violate the DRY Principle. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger: Assuming that arrays are of the same type and with equal number of elements, the more pragmatic way would be to condense them into single data structure. This means, that you could also initialize them at once (for example, using the loop), instead of repeating the (same) initializer each time.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski
I see... Can you tell me how that would be done?

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger: I believe that unwind's answer has already given the solution you might consider.

Comment: You might consider using [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) instead. It doesn't have many restrictions except space as a separator (though pure numbers are ... numbers).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen
As much as I'd love to, I'm programming on the Sega Saturn, a video game  console from 1994 with an architecture that's very difficult to understand. C is quite literally my only option besides ASM, and would make things exponentially more difficult, as the Saturn has more than 4 different processors.

Comment: How does your code decide to use `_300[]` array vs. `_099[]` array? If there is a switch or an if based on a number, then the array of pointers or two-dimensional array is what you need.

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger FWIW, it's easy to embed Forth-like languages into arbitrary platforms. We did this for a number of games back in Saturn and pre-Saturn days.

Comment: From what you are saying you should do as some other people has suggested and just have a multidimensional array or a structure called `heightMasks`, that would be the most organized, because you would have all the related `heightMask` in one place, it will be easier to maintain and understand. Having 300 arrays is not maintainable. Also names should be descriptive, _001, doesn't mean anything, even heighMask1 is better. If this is a project only for yourself, that's "ok", but think if someone else in the future is to read it, what is the best strategy for readability?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not possible to do this, no.

However, you can begin the variable name with any valid character (such as a letter or underscore) and then make the rest numbers.

For example, instead of `int 001[4]` you could do `int _001[4]`.

For people just reading my answer - shoutout to unwind who answered below on how this is not great design for human reading or usability. See and upvote his answer too for more details.

Comment: The underscore is very clean! Defenitely prefered over slapping a letter before it, thanks so much for letting me know you can do that.

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger better to use a letter. Just as clean and no probs with any reserved use of leading `_underscore`.

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger no problem! Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Also, do you know why stackoverflow won't let me edit my comments? I made 2 typos in my response to you.

Comment: Editing comments has nothing to do with reputation. Everyone is allowed to edit their comments for 5 minutes, then that's it. They are cast in stone (until you delete them, of course!)

Answer (score 72):

This is very strange design.

A number is really not a name, in the human sense. Nobody reading the code will understand the meaning of an array called `_031`.

You should figure out what all of these arrays have in common, and use a single multi-dimensional array with a descriptive name.

So instead of

```
int _001[4];
int _002[4];
...
int _300[4];
```

you should have something like

```
int whatever[300][4];
```

Then wherever you used to access `_002`, you'd just access `whatever[1]` instead. Much cleaner. If you want to you can add one and make it `301` and use 1-based indexes.

Comment: I suppose I could do this. Is there a speed benefit of any kind? Or is it simply for organization? Later down the line, I'm going to have an array of 256 that points to different combinations of the numbered arrays, and I feel like it'd be easier just to type _025 instead of whatever[25].

Comment: There is probably no speed benefit, but most likely no penalty either. And it's really *much cleaner*. Any time where you're having lots of similar things that belong together, you should use an array. I'm sorry but I don't understand your example. If you have a secondary array that indexes into the first, that works equally well with all 300 arrays together, of course.

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger You could just [use an array named `_`](http://ideone.com/wCYTR3), or any short, but valid name.  [Note that I'm not 100% certain about C's rules for file scope identifiers that start with `_`, and that name _might_ be invalid according to the standard.]

Answer (score 0):

No, and never.

Remember kids, the regex for identifiers (C-wise) is `[_a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*`, and the regex for decimal numbers (C-wise) is `[0-9]*`! Your compiler can literally see `000` (etc.) as a decimal number and instead 'wrongfully' take it as an expression which will then create a massive compiler catastrophe!

EDIT: **Why C disallow number prefixed identifier?**

There's one important concept that C allowed **suffix**.

For example, consider this pseudo-code:

`int 01234;
int 01234l;`

If we modified the regex of identifiers to `[_0-9a-zA-Z]*`, not only that it will overlap the range of decimal numbers, it may also overlap the range of special suffix like `l`, `ul`, `f` or `d` too. We humans can sure read and group those thing, but computers can't! Computers cannot solve ambiguity or otherwise it will an eternal death!

Comment: The suffixes are not really a problem. The initial-0, for example, makes the compiler look for an octal number: `0123`, and it will reject `0128`. But consider the very simple case `int 1 = 2; int x = 1;`. What value is in `x`?